# How can i randomly generate Public and Private key for Eos account with flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, eos

I have been using Eosdart package of flutter for connecting and calling action on  EOS blockcahin but there is no method for creating EOS accocut  keys.
Is there any way through which we can create Eos account keys with flutter app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating private key we have different package other  than Eosdart and u can check it here [Eosdart_ecc package for generating public and private keys](https://pub.dev/packages/eosdart_ecc)